# Does this circuit look proper?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

We have to draw 3A in peak bursts, so I computed 55 mils wide for this amount of current. The footprint on this drawing is of a transistor, that has a small footprint. Would it be best to keep it this way or reduce the track width?

If track width reduction is necessary, please comment if successive reductions are necessary.

[image]

Comment: Great title put me off reading it.

Comment: You should go out of the transistor pad with a smaller trace and enlarge it later. As it is you could have problems for soldering and reworking the part

Comment: @Andyaka, glad you like it

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami means "thermal relief" but used other words for it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, this design can make it a bit difficult for the board shop. Could be more chances of an error from the manufacturers. Something to the effect of curves are less preferred than to angles. I've made a few boards, so I could be wrong, but that came at the advice of a few other engineers.

When having to do things like this, I always made a polygon that connected the larger trace to the the pad, encompasses the whole pad. Especially with 3A peaks, I'd feel more comfortable with the entire pad being attached to the trace/polygon. I'd also edit the component on the left so that the traces land in the middle at a 90 degree angle, but that's just me.

This probably should have been a comment, but I don't have the rep for that.